# Objective C Xcode header error

Tags: objective-c, xcode, header-files

.m file

```
#import "BNREmployee.h"

@interface BNREmployee ()

@property (weak) IBOutlet NSWindow *window;

@end
@implementation BNREmployee
- (double)yearsOfEmployment {
   **Use of undeclared identifier 'applicationDidFinishLaunching'** -(void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(NSNotification *)aNotification {
    // Do I have a non-nil hireDate?
    if (self.hireDate) {
        // NSTimeInterval is the same as double
        NSDate *now = [NSDate date];
        NSTimeInterval secs = [now timeIntervalSinceDate:self.hireDate];
        return secs / 31557600.0; // Seconds per year
    } else {
        return 0;
    }  
}
- (float) bodyMassIndex
{
    float normalBMI = [super bodyMassIndex];
    return normalBMI * 0.9;
}
}
- (void)applicationWillTerminate:(NSNotification *)aNotification {
    // Insert code here to tear down your application
}


@end
```

.h file

```
#import "BNRPerson.h"

@interface BNREmployee : BNRPerson

@property (nonatomic) unsigned int employeeID;
@property (nonatomic) unsigned int officeAlarmCode;
@property (nonatomic) NSDate *hireDate;
- (double)yearsOfEmployment;

@end
```

I was prompted in another answer to use { after -(double)yearsOfEmployment but the line after it is another header where the variable 'applicationDidFinishLaunching' is not declared anywhere else since it is a universal variable already implemented in Xcode. Thats why I was wondering how to get my syntax straight in order to not have a compiler error.

Comment: It looks like you are not programming a long time. You should understand the syntax of a language before starting to program. Get some tutorials on the web like here https://www.thenewboston.com/videos.php?cat=33

Comment: Please mark the correct answer if you could solve your problem to close this post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can not declare a method inside another method. You should have your methods like this:

```
-(void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(NSNotification *)aNotification {

}

- (double)yearsOfEmployment {

    // Do I have a non-nil hireDate?
    if (self.hireDate) {
        // NSTimeInterval is the same as double
        NSDate *now = [NSDate date];
        NSTimeInterval secs = [now timeIntervalSinceDate:self.hireDate];
        return secs / 31557600.0; // Seconds per year
    } else {
        return 0;
    }  
}

- (float) bodyMassIndex {
    float normalBMI = [super bodyMassIndex];
    return normalBMI * 0.9;
}

- (void)applicationWillTerminate:(NSNotification *)aNotification {
    // Insert code here to tear down your application
}
```

And inside another method you can call your predefined methods like this:

```
[self yearsOfEmployment];
```

or

```
CGFloat myFloat = [self bodyMassIndex];
```

But normally you shouldn't have any of the **application methods** inside another class than `AppDelegate`. `AppDelegate` handles the basic stuff like background processes and things which will be called at the start of an app.

Answer (score 0):

`applicationDidFinishLaunching:` is not a "global variable". It's the name of a method that classes conforming to `UIApplicationDelegate` must implement. So take it out of your implementation of `yearsOfEmployment`.

E.g.,

```
- (double)yearsOfEmployment {
    // Do I have a non-nil hireDate?
    if (self.hireDate) {
        // NSTimeInterval is the same as double
        NSDate *now = [NSDate date];
        NSTimeInterval secs = [now timeIntervalSinceDate:self.hireDate];
        return secs / 31557600.0; // Seconds per year
    } else {
        return 0;
    }  
}
```

However, you have other problems beyond these. Your `BNREmployee` class sure looks like a model class. I can't for the life of me fathom why you would have something like `applicationDidFinishLaunching:` or `applicationWillTerminate:` inside of it. These methods belong in one place only: the single class—and effective singleton—that implements `UIApplicationDelegate` in your application.